# WebDriverIO/Appium Error: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 1)

Tags: typescript, react-native, automation, appium, webdriver-io

I'm encountering an error while running WebDriverIO tests with Appium. The error message is as follows:

[0-0] 2023-10-20T12:37:56.830Z ERROR @wdio/appium-service: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 1)

- WebDriverIO version
- Appium version
- Test framework used (e.g., Mocha)
- Relevant portions of your WebDriverIO configuration (**`wdio.conf.js`**).